# Zero set is closed topology

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

> Given $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on a topological space $X$, I want to show that the zero set of $f$, $Z(f) := \{x ∈ X: f(x) = 0\}$, is closed.

To do so, should I start by showing the complement of the zero set is open? Or consider a point and use the epsilon delta definition?

Comment: $Z(f) = f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed in $X$ since $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: There is no "epsilon-delta definition" of open, that is for *continuity*. The metric (!) definition of open just uses $\epsilon$, as it were. But $X$ is not metric (but a general topological space), so it does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've had the idea of showing that the complement of the zero set is open, you *should* investigate to see if starting that way can lead to a proof.

In general, you only know whether an idea works *after* you've explored it, not *before*. There is no rule in mathematics that says "In problems like P, thou shalt do X" — the closest you get is something like "In problems like P, the approaches X, Y, and Z are often informative".

Problems where all you have to do is follow a script to arrive at an answer are the exception, not the rule. (but we study them a lot, because it's really, *really* useful to have classes of problems you know you can solve ahead of time)

In this particular problem, fortune smiles upon thee; there exists a rather short proof that starts with your idea, using only the very basic topological facts, along with the knowledge that $\{ 0 \} $ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and you are likely to come across it.

---

The other idea of using "the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition" might be *informative*, but will ultimately be inadequate for a complete proof; that approach can only possibly work for those spaces $X$ on which limits of real-valued functions are actually given by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ characterization.

Answer (score 0):

$f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous iff for all open sets $O$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}[O] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in O\}$ is open in $X$, or equivalently for all closed sets $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $X$.

As in all metric spaces, any set of the form $\{x\}$ is closed.

So the definition of continuity tells us that $Z(f) = \{x \in X: f(x) = 0\}= \{x \in X: f(x) = \{0\}\} = f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is a closed set of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

You could do both in the case of real numbers, but in general topology only the first one works (and only if its a Frechet space with an element called $0$). If it's a Frechet space then any singleton is closed and the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous mapping is closed meaning that $\{x: f(x)=a\}$ is an open set.

The second one you don't actually need to use delta-epsilon definition directly. Instead you use the fact that if you have a sequence $x_n\in Z(f)$ that is convergent in $\mathbb R$ then you have that since $f(x_n)=0$ and $f$ is continuous then $f(\lim x_n)=0$ meaning that $\lim x_n\in Z(f)$.